# Email2Case : How to edit the subject of the reply/Forward email

Tags: email, case, email2case

Once we created an Email to case,Salesforce will create a Case,
In the Emails related list of the case contains the original message.

What I need to know is;

1. Is it possible to change the email subject **WHEN** I'm forwarding or replying to the email?
2. If it is possible how could I do this?
3. If this is not possible are there any alternatives?

[image: Case : Email Related List]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think that you can do that by 1. opening the specific email 2. click Forward 3. you will be able to edit the subject manually in that screen